# drawing of heightmap gives weird single pixels

Tags: opengl, c++, glsl

I'm working on a game where I want to generate a heightmap, however it draws a bunch of random white dots in a mostly black background, the function I have looks as following:

```
void heightmap::layer1(int viewx,float freq1){


    for(int depth=1;depth<80;depth=depth+5){

        for(int x=0;x<screenWidth-1;x=x+5){

            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glColor3f(0.4, 0.2, 0.1);

                float h2=getCoord(viewx+x-5,depth+5,freq1);     
                glVertex3f(viewx+x-5,h2,depth+5);

                 h2=getCoord(viewx+x,depth+5,freq1);        
                glVertex3f(viewx+x,h2,depth+5 );

                 h2=getCoord(viewx+x,depth,freq1);      
                glVertex3f(viewx+x,h2,depth );

                 h2=getCoord(viewx+x-5,depth,freq1);        
                glVertex3f(viewx+x-5,h2,depth);

            glEnd();
    }
}
```

where get getCoord returns the height which takes a value between 0 and 800. However when I run this I get only darkness, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image: a few random dots]

The problem also exists for the code

```
    for(int depth=1;depth<10;depth=depth+5){

            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        for(int x=0;x<screenWidth-1;x=x+20){


                glColor3f(1, 1, 1);


                float h2=getCoord(viewx+x,depth,freq1);     
                glVertex3f(viewx+x,depth,h2 );

                 h2=getCoord(viewx+x,depth+5,freq1);        
                glVertex3f(viewx+x,depth+5 ,h2);


    }
            glEnd();        
}
```

When I force the values to be between [image]

However I fixed the getCoords function to now simply return depth/80.0f. Meaning that I would expect a square not this shape, how do I fix this so that it will actually generate a terrain with the heigh given by the getcoords function?

Comment: The complete code is quite large so if you need some specific information feel free to ask.

Comment: I also tried flipping the order of drawing around but that didn't work either.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should do yourself a favour and learn [modern OpenGL](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/); the `glBegin` etc. functions you are using have been deprecated for almost 10 years.